# How to get names of data.table columns by specific conditions?

Tags: r, parallel-processing, data.table

I have a `data.table` object `resultList` with columns named `"V1:V128"` and some rows. I want to get the names of those columns which fulfill conditions like

```
lapply(.SD, mean) < a
```

I tried to do this:

```
names(resultList[, lapply(.SD, mean) < 0])
```

But I had no effect. What code does realize this?

Second question - is it possible to use `parLapply` instead of `lapply` for `data.table` (for example, use `parLapply(cl, .SD, mean)` instead of `lapply(.SD, mean)`)?

Comment: I am not sure that the parallel-processing tag is appropriate here.

Comment: @Imo, using parLapply  is a second part of question. What tag is better here?

Comment: Ah, I missed that part. It's good style to use backticks to highlight functions and package names. I haven't seen anyone using any of the parallel packages with `data.table`.

Comment: Generally a good idea to ask one question per post here. Because that's the convention, you'll often find folks totally missing your second, third, fourth, ... question in the same post.

Comment: Sorry, guys, I though that Okkam blade was useful here...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

To get the names of the columns with a mean less than some specific value you could do this:

```
dt = data.table(a = rep(1,10), b = rep(10,10))
colnames(dt)[colMeans(dt) < 10]
## [1] "a"
```

Or a bit more diomatic `data.table` approach would be

```
colnames(dt)[dt[, lapply(.SD, mean) < 10]]
## [1] "a"
```

See also data.table's [Do's and Don'ts](https://github.com/Rdatatable/data.table/wiki/Do%27s-and-Don%27ts#5-dont-use-colsums-use-lapply-on-sd)

Comment: What is the rule of thumb for answering as a comment vs an answer?

Comment: The rule of thumb for using `apply` with margin 2 on a data table is to not do it

Comment: @PierreLafortune Did not know you weren't supposed to do that.

Comment: It has unintended consequences. Plus, we should never do `apply(obj, 2, mean)`. There is an efficient function for that, `colMeans`. And while we're at it, `apply(obj, 1, mean)` should be `rowMeans`.

Comment: @PierreLafortune It can be specific function, not mean, but, for example, kurtosis or any function which has no internal realization.

Comment: @Dmitriy do not use `apply(obj, 2, ...)` with any `data.frame` or `data.table`

Comment: So, I use faq for data.table. https://rawgit.com/wiki/Rdatatable/data.table/vignettes/datatable-intro.html   To compute on (multiple) columns, we can then simply use the base R function lapply().

DT[, lapply(.SD, mean), by = ID]

Comment: Or do you want to say that's the bad way to use external *apply for data.table object?

Comment: @Dmitriy if you use lapply in that way you're taking the mean across a row, not the column like we did above. I also don't see in the lapply help that it converts it to a matrix first. I don't think it would need to since it just applys a function to one level of x... I may be wrong on that part though.

Comment: @Kristofersen I have colMean by this code with lapply.  An example:  > dt = data.table(a = rep(1,10), b = rep(10,10))
> colnames(dt)[colMeans(dt) < 10]
[1] "a"
> dt
    a  b
 1: 1 10
 2: 1 10
 3: 1 10
 4: 1 10
 5: 1 10
 6: 1 10
 7: 1 10
 8: 1 10
 9: 1 10
10: 1 10
> dt[,lapply(.SD, mean)]
   a  b
1: 1 10
>       but > colMeans(dt)
 a  b 
 1 10 
> rowMeans(dt)
 [1] 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5 5.5
>

Comment: @Dmitriy right, sorry, i misunderstood that.

Comment: Yes @Dmitriy that is correct usage. See answer edit.